# Spliting a user input string by ":"

Tags: java

I want to get a user input using a JOptionPane input box and split the user's input into 2 sections. (I'm a student so I have to use JOptionPane.)
For example, I want to get the start time, 20:54, and split it to

```
startHour = 20;
startMin = 54;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the split function of `String` class which return an array of string values then index 0 contain the hour, index 1 contain the minutes:

note: you need to cast the string value to int

```
String value = "20:54";
String [] parts = value.split(":");
int startHour = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
int startMin = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Comment: @Hulk Its better to store it in array and access array by index.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!

Comment: [`parseInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) would avoid unnecessary boxing `int` to `Integer`.

Comment: @BennyKerido I updated the code with using `Integer.ParseInt()` instead of using `valueOf` which cause unnecessary boxing.

Comment: There is no casting in your example. There is only parsing the string to an integer. Typecasting is a specific operation in Java (and C).

Comment: sorry, For the wrong describing, I tried to parse the value of string to int.